# Cardinality of HK

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ and $K$ be two subgroups of $G.$ If both $H$ and $K$ have $12$ elements which of following numbers cannot be cardinality of set $HK=\{hk:h \in H, k \in K\}$?

1.72

2.60

3.48

4.36

I know $|HK|= \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$. But what manipulations are required to get answer which is 60?

Comment: $60$ cannot be the cardinality. The cardinality must be a divisor of $144$.

Comment: $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of both $H$ and $K$. Use Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: What if we had more than one options which were not divisors of 144

Comment: Why are you trying to make an easy question more difficult?

Comment: @DerekHolt: I think OP wants to know whether other values are possible to attain or not. I tried to give an answer. If you please see it.

Comment: But what he actually asked was "What if we had more than one options which were not divisors of 144" which we don't!

Answer (score 2):

$|HK| = \frac{|H|\cdot|K|}{|H \cap K|}.$ Now $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $K.$ So by Lagrange's theorem, possible orders of $H \cap K$ are $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12.$ Hence the possible orders of $HK$ are $144, 72, 48, 36, 24, 12.$ Note that, $|H \cap K| = 12 \Leftrightarrow H=K. $

Now you can ask is it possible to attain all other possible values? And it is indeed possible. Consider the following examples:

(1). $G = \mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{12}, H = \mathbb Z_{12} \times (0), K = (0) \times \mathbb Z_{12}.$

(2). $G = \mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{6}, H = \mathbb Z_{12} \times (0), K = (\bar 6) \times \mathbb Z_{6}.$

(3). $G = \mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{4}, H = \mathbb Z_{12} \times (0), K = (\bar 4) \times \mathbb Z_{4}.$

(4). $G = \mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{3}, H = \mathbb Z_{12} \times (0), K = (\bar 3) \times \mathbb Z_{3}.$

(5). $G = \mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{2}, H = \mathbb Z_{12} \times (0), K = (\bar 2) \times \mathbb Z_{2.}$